# Unable to move primary key fields into foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I've created to two tables name **STUDENT** and **ROOM** which in my case is a one to one relation. The *primary key* from **STUDENT** table is a *foreign key* in **ROOM** but when i insert data into student its doesn't update values in *foreign key* of room. 
 
There were many similar question about this in mysql and sqlserver but not in oracle sql.

Comment: Why do you expect anything being updated in ROOM when you insert records in STUDENT??? What should happen there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for cascading updates.
Check out this article:-
http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html?m=1
The script from article generates a package and three triggers which will do cascade updates.